# How to disappear alert after 5 seconds in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
import { useState } from 'react'
    
    const Message = ({ variant, children }) => {
      const [timeOut, setTimeOut] = useState(null)
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTimeOut(1)
      }, 3000)
    
      return (
        timeOut !== 1 && <div className={`alert alert-${variant}`}>{children}</div>
      )
    }
    
    Message.defaultPros = {
      variant: 'info',
    }
    
    export default Message
```

I want to disappear this alert after 2 or 3 seconds. I used this logic it's fine and working but In my console, I'm having this warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

Is it affecting my app or is it oka? You can give me a better idea to implement this logic.

Comment: The aim of an alert is to make sure the user acknowledges something. The way you can be "sure" of that is having the user click on the close button: s/he performed a voluntary interaction therefore s/he must have seen it. An alert that automatically closes after a few seconds defeats that purpose: maybe the user got distracted while it was displayed and s/he did not see it before it closed. So, if the message is so important you have to be sure it has been seen, the alert should not close on timeout, if it is not, you should not use an alert but some less invasive form of notification.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can read through the comments

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    
const Message = ({ variant, children }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  // On componentDidMount set the timer
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
      // After 3 seconds set the show value to false
      setShow(false)
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeId)
    }
  }, []);

  // If show is false the component will return null and stop here
  if (!show) {
    return null;
  }

  // If show is true this will be returned
  return (
    <div className={`alert alert-${variant}`}>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

Message.defaultPros = {
  variant: 'info',
}

export default Message;
```

Comment: Still, I'm having WARNING in console

Comment: You need to clear the timeId, if the component unmounts. However I don't know why your component unmounts before 3 seconds. You have a parent component that you are not showing in your question

Comment: for example the alert it shows when I login with the wrong information. the first time is okay but if do it again wrong info within 3 seconds, that's the time the WARNING is appearing.

Comment: Did you try the code I updated? Notice in the useEffect there is a return function, which is handles componentWillUnmount

Answer (score 4):

This will show the alert during 3 seconds, then it will disappear :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Message = ({ variant, children }) => {
  // the alert is displayed by default
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true);
      
  useEffect(() => {
    // when the component is mounted, the alert is displayed for 3 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(false);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);     
    
  return (
    {alert && <div className={`alert alert-${variant}`}>{children}</div>}
  )
}
```

Comment: Still, I'm having WARNING in console

Comment: what's the warning ? do you have ```import React``` on top of your component ?

Comment: "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function." This is the warning and it show when i send a message while timeout is not finished it's job.   Yes am using React 17 it's already imported.

Comment: it probably comes from another component, do you use ```useEffect``` somewhere else

Comment: YES. if I wait for 3 seconds everytime, the alert is fine but when I call that alert 2 or 3 times consecutive It show WARNING

Answer (score 3):

If you use MUI, then you can make alerts appear and disapper with fade in transitions.
Here's the code

```
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import AlertTitle from "@mui/material/AlertTitle";
import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";

export default function Registration() {

  const [alertVisibility, setAlertVisibility] = useState(false);

  return(
    <Fade
       in={alertVisibility} //Write the needed condition here to make it appear
       timeout={{ enter: 1000, exit: 1000 }} //Edit these two values to change the duration of transition when the element is getting appeared and disappeard
       addEndListener={() => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           setAlertVisibility(true)
         }, 2000);
       }}
       >
       <Alert severity="success" variant="standard" className="alert">
          <AlertTitle>Success</AlertTitle>
             Registration Successful!
          </Alert>
    </Fade>
  )
}
```

For more transitions refer this -> https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/

Comment: I believe its suppose to be `setAlertVisibility(false)` instead of 'true'

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Message = ({ variant, children }) => {

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(true);
      
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(false);
    }, 3000);
    
    // To clear or cancel a timer, you call the clearTimeout(); method, 
    // passing in the timer object that you created into clearTimeout().
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);     
    
  return (
    {alert && <div className={`alert alert-${variant}`}>{children}</div>}
  )
}
```